# Strip last field from numeric string conditionally

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed, grep

I have a large file that I need to conditionally remove the last numeric field in only from the lines that start with the numbers 1-19. I want to print out the whole file, line by line, including those lines that do not meet the condition.

Here is my code:

```
cat > test.txt
118222
1 0.5632 0.10 0.05 1.00 0.45 5.00 0.50 0
0.54 0.49 0.58 0.74 1.08 1.75 1.97 1.86 1.51 1.03 0.76 0.52
0.22 0.20 0.21 0.25 0.37 0.58 0.61 0.64 0.55 0.45 0.39 0.23
0.17 0.20 0.18 0.14 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.09 0.09 0.11 0.12
5 0.0172 0.10 0.05 1.00 0.45 5.00 0.50 1
0.35 0.32 0.39 0.71 1.15 1.87 1.96 1.72 1.36 0.91 0.70 0.43
0.31 0.30 0.29 0.27 0.36 0.57 0.57 0.57 0.46 0.35 0.34 0.31
0.28 0.29 0.26 0.16 0.11 0.11 0.12 0.11 0.11 0.10 0.14 0.26

#!/bin/bash

FILE=test.text
while read i; do
 echo ${i} | grep -E '^([1-9]|1[0-9])' && sed 's/.$//' || echo ${i}
done < $FILE
```

This doesn't work, although the grep and sed lines work individually.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional substitution in `sed`.

```
sed '/^\([1-9]\|1[0-9]\) /s/.$//' test.text
```

I've added a space after the number match at the beginning. Otherwise, it will also match `118222`, which isn't in the `1-19` range, because it begins with `1`.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/QQqjXX)

Your title says you want to remove the last character from the line, the question says the last *numeric* character.  For the latter, it should be:

```
sed '/^\([1-9]\|1[0-9]\) /s/[0-9]\([^0-9]*\)$/\1/' test.text
```

Comment: Yes, this completely works. I used the second one, since I did want to remove a numeric character. Sorry for the lack of clarity in my title. I really need to spend more time on the sed tutorials. Thank you!